# IntelliJ Plugin Development: How do I access the line separator property?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How do I find out the line separator property of the current document that I am working on while writing an IntelliJ plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VirtualFile.getDetectedLineSeparator()`.